# Is it possible to rename a file being used by pm2 without having to delete it?

Tags: node.js, rename, pm2, file-rename

Let's say I have a pm2 process `pm2 start app.js`
This process has the id #3 among a list of other process, and I've been used to this id for over a year. Now, I'd like to rename app.js to foo.js

Is there a way to do so without having to delete the process and create a new one, which would give me a new id on top of the list.
I've searched for a file to edit where the file to execute should be pointed but can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by -

```
pm2 delete id|name  
pm2 start app.js -n newname
```

or

```
pm2 restart id|name -n newname
```

Comment: I think that delete+start give me a new id equals to the highest in existance+1, and for the -n parameter, it's for the name you give to your process as an alias, not the actual file name

Answer (score 0):

I just gave it a try but didn't had much hope. I refactored my file's name, pushed it. As expected after pulling the update on the server it didn't worked as the file's name change.

So to keep my process list as it used to be before, I had to `pm2 delete all` to remove all the existing process, then `pm2 kill` to reset the id list to 0, then I added back all my process back in the same order it was before.

I'm not marking it as the correct answer as I had to reinstall everything, but for me it go solve